# how to find suspicious process details and its command line arguments

Tags: linux, process

On my Linux server, i am getting a suspicious perl process, which is trying to send spam from my server, using a perl script. Here is the `ps -aux` output.

```
apache     10078  0.0  0.0   4028   705 pts/1    S+   15:50   0:00 [perl]
apache     10079  0.0  0.0   4023   433 pts/1    S+   15:50   0:00 [perl]
apache     10080  0.0  0.0   4024   432 pts/1    S+   15:50   0:00 [perl]
.
.
.
```

There are more than 20 of such processes running and each one of them is consuming a lot of Sockets.

unable to find the script's location, path and detail as its just "perl" written there.
I tried to use lsof to see its opened files, it shows a big number of sockets and files opened by one website hosted on my server. but i cannot get a clue from there that which script is this, so that i can track and remove it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lsof -p` against the relevant process ID's will tell you where to look...

For instance, `lsof -p 10078` will give you a listing of all the open files associated with that process. Take a look at the output and work back to see which files are in use.

Comment: that i have already tried. but does it reveals the information about the actual path of the script? that where it is located?

Comment: It's probably a CGI script. Restart Apache and see if it goes away.

Comment: it does go away but comes back at random intervals in a day.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution using which you can know the Exact path of the system/kernel perocess, enclosed in brackets , like [perl]

```
readlink -f /proc/{PID of process}/exe
```